# Ruby YAML problem when deserializing a nested object structure

Tags: ruby, serialization, yaml

I have 3 classes that have the following relationship:

**Battlefield** have an array of teams.

**BattleTeam** have an array of members, and a reference to the **Battlefield**.

**Jaguar** is a member of a **BattleTeam** and has a reference to it.

If I serialize/deserialize Jaguar and up to BattleTeam, there is no problem. The problem happens when serializing/deserializing a Battlefield.

Serializing it yields the appropiate result, but deserializing it turns the members in BattleTeam to nil.

Let me show you:

```
>> j = Jaguar.new
=> #<Jaguar:0xa2221f8 @vitality=nil, @spirituality=nil, @log=nil, @name=nil>

#A battleteam might have many members:
>> t = BattleTeam.new
=> #<BattleTeam:0xa21fafc @members=[], @dead_members=[]>

#A battlefield might have many teams:
>> b = Battlefield.new
=> #<Battlefield:0xa2075d8 @teams=[]>

#Add a member to the team
>> t.add_member(j)
=> #<BattleTeam:0xa21fafc @members=[#<Jaguar:0xa2221f8 @vitality=nil, @spirituality=nil, @log=nil, @name=nil, @battle_team=#<BattleTeam:0xa21fafc ...>], dead_members[]

#Add a team to the battlefield
>> b.add_team(t)
=> #<Battlefield:0xa2075d8 @teams=[#<BattleTeam:0xa21fafc @members=[#<Jaguar:0xa2221f8 @vitality=nil, @spirituality=nil, @log=nil, @name=nil, @battle_team=#<BattleTeam:0xa21fafc ...>>], @dead_members=[], @battlefield=#<Battlefield:0xa2075d8 ...>>]>

#Serialize and deserialize the jaguar object (it works as expected):
>> YAML::load j.to_yaml
=> #<Jaguar:0xa1e3cdc @vitality=nil, @spirituality=nil, @log=nil, @name=nil, @battle_team=#<BattleTeam:0xa1e4204 @members=[#<Jaguar:0xa1e3cdc ...>], dead_members[], battlefield#<Battlefield:0xa1e4038 @teams=[#<BattleTeam:0xa1e4204 ...>]

#Serialize and deserialize the battle team object (it words as expected):
>> YAML::load t.to_yaml
=> #<BattleTeam:0xa1d0664 @members=[#<Jaguar:0xa1cfee4 @vitality=nil, @spirituality=nil, @log=nil, @name=nil, @battle_team=#<BattleTeam:0xa1d0664 ...>], dead_members[], battlefield#<Battlefield:0xa1d0470 @teams=[#<BattleTeam:0xa1d0664 ...>]

#Serialize and deserialize the battle team object
#(here the @members array is deserialized as nil, this is not expected!):
>> YAML::load b.to_yaml
=> #<Battlefield:0xa1c370c @teams=[#<BattleTeam:0xa1c33b0 @members=nil, @dead_members=[], @battlefield=#<Battlefield:0xa1c370c ...>]

>> YAML::load(b.to_yaml).teams[0].members
=> nil


#Here is the generated yaml, it looks right, the member is there:
>> puts b.to_yaml
--- &id002 !ruby/object:Battlefield 
teams: 
- &id001 !ruby/object:BattleTeam 
  battlefield: *id002
  dead_members: []

  members: 
  - !ruby/object:Jaguar 
    battle_team: *id001
    log: 
    name: 
    spirituality: 
    vitality: 
=> nil
```

Anyone knows what's wrong with this?

Comment: Please don't post your complete program. Most people don't wanna spend all day answering your question. Try to find the smallest example, which still shows the symptoms. Then we can try to help you see, why ruby works not the way you expected.

Comment: In fact, it isn't the complete program. I left out the class definitions.

Just put there the simplest example I could provide that fails: a nested structure with 2 level nesting, that's why 3 different instances are needed. It doesn't fail with just 2.

I don't know how I could make it simpler.

Comment: We need simple class definitions to test this out.

Comment: And yeah, it is a bug, had some people reproduce it.

If you are interested in reproducing I'll post the code.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know much about YAML or serializing / deserializing..
But look :

puts b.to_yaml
--- &id002 !ruby/object:Battlefield 
teams: 
- &id001 !ruby/object:BattleTeam 
  battlefield: *id002
  dead_members: []

members: 
  - !ruby/object:Jaguar 
    battle_team: *id001
    log: 
    name: 
    spirituality: 
    vitality: 
=> nil

How come battlefield and battleteam look like this:

```
--- &id002 !ruby/object:Battlefield 
- &id001 !ruby/object:BattleTeam
```

And Jaguar looks like this:

```
  - !ruby/object:Jaguar
```

The id seems to be missing... ?

Comment: Ah, no, it is correct.

That happens because no other object references the Jaguar instance, so it doesn't need an id.
It is created "inside" the BattleTeam instance.